# How to control spaces/margin between bars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flot

I can't seem to find how to control spaces/margin between bars. I am trying to add 10px space between every bar. I could do this with CSS, though, this does not sound like a valid approach.

API documentation: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt

Comment: The only solution I have found so far is to use lineWidth + background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can have control over the bar width simply decreasing the number of hours in the day. This can be achieved using:

```
barWidth: [number of hours] * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

Making `[number of hours]` anything below `24` will create spaces between the tabs.